# Why would a function signature have a unit parameter following other parameters?

Tags: f#, unit-type

I am looking at a function that I saw on a training course and cannot understand the use of "()" at the end of the following function:

```
let acclock (start:DateTimeOffset) rate () =
    let now = DateTime.Now
    let elapsed = now - start
    start.AddTicks (elapsed.Ticks * rate)
```

Why would a function signature have a unit parameter at the end of other parameters on its signature?

Hence, I thought that a unit parameter meant no parameter or return type which would be similar to "void".

Comment: Just FYI; in a FPL like F# a function like `unit -> int` means that it's a function that takes a unit value. Not like it's usually interpreted in C-like languages; a function that takes no values. This is to me one of the many small benefits of FP over C-like languages. In C# you often need special handling for the `void` case (like `Task` and `Task<>`). In F# a function always takes and returns a value which no special handling is needed for the `unit` value. The reason it's called unit is because it maps to `unit` category which is a category that has only one value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with partial application.  You can bind this function to another name, providing both the `start` and `rate` parameter, creating a function of type `() -> DateTime`.  Only when you call that function, you will execute the calculation of "elapsed = now - start" and "start.AddTicks". Like this:

```
let timeThis =
    let stopClock = acclock DateTime.Now 500
    doStuff ()
    stopClock () // The function is only executed now
```

If you would not have the `()` parameter at the end, you would execute that statement directly if you add the `rate` value.

```
let acclock' (start:DateTimeOffset) rate =
    let now = DateTime.Now
    let elapsed = now - start
    start.AddTicks (elapsed.Ticks * rate)

let timeThis1 =
    let stopClock = acclock' DateTime.Now
    doStuff ()
    stopClock 500 // This is only executed now

// Or
let timeThis2 =
    let stopClock = acclock' DateTime.Now 500 // Wait, we calculated it immediately
    doStuff ()
    stopClock // This is just a value
```

Answer (score 4):

With the additional `()`, you can pass the `start` and `rate` parameters and get a partially applied function `unit -> DateTime`.

```
let partiallyAppliedAcclock = acclock DateTime.Now 1L

val partiallyAppliedAcclock : (unit -> System.DateTime)
```

Without the `()`, it would be a `DateTime` value.

```
let acclockValue = acclock2 DateTime.Now 1L // acclock defined without ()

val acclockValue : DateTime = 06-12-15 3:20:41 PM
```

The difference is not important for pure functions (you can always replace a call to a pure function with its value), but `acclock` is not pure. It uses `DateTime.Now`, so every time it's called the result will be different.